# MATLAB scripts and fortran scripts are used in a for loop of a bash script. Can I avoid call MATLAB multiple times?

Tags: bash, matlab, fortran

I have a bash shell script that runs multiple MATLAB and fortran codes within a for loop.

In the loop, the bash script calls MATLAB over and over again. This make the script inefficient.

I use MATLAB 2017b and Mac OS X Catalina(10.15.7).

Any suggestions?

```sh
#!/bin/bash 
 
for i in {1..10}
do
    cp initial_input_$i initial_input
    matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r "matlab1; exit;"
    cp matlat1.output fortran1.input
    gfortran fortran1.f 
    ./a.out
    cp fortran1.output matlab2.input
    matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r "matlab2; exit;"
    cp matlab2.output fortran2.input
    gfortran fortran2.f 
    ./a.out
    cp fortran2.output matlab3.input
    matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r "matlab3; exit;"
    cp matlab3.output fortran3.input
    gfortran fortran3.f 
    ./a.out
    cp fortran3.output final_output_$i
done
```

Comment: I would just write that loop in MATLAB. It is easy to call an external program, no need to do this in a shell script. Also, I don't understand why you re-compile your Fortran program over and over again, why no do that just once before the loop?

Comment: And I might also convert the Fortran program into a MEX file and do away with the apparent use of files to exchange data between the programs.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in plain Matlab way to do this on Mac or Linux; it doesn't run in a "client/server" mode where there's a persistent Matlab process that takes multiple commands. (If you were on Windows, you could use Matlab's ["COM Automation Server" mode](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-matlab-com-automation-server.html) to do this.)

The official MathWorks way to do this would probably be to use their [Matlab Production Server](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-production-server.html) product, which is a server that runs a pool of Matlab workers that you can dispatch calls to via a JSON API. But that's pretty heavyweight and enterprisey for your environment, doesn't run on Mac at all, and will cost you like $20,000.

If you *really* wanted to do this with Matlab in a client-server way, you could write a Matlab program that causes Matlab to operate as a server: Have it run a loop that waits for input by checking a directory for new files or listening on a socket, and then when new input arrives, use `eval()` to run it, and then returns to the loop to wait for more input. When you're all done with it, send it an `exit` command.

But that's kind of a lot of work, and debugging multi-process communication stuff like that is hard. So what I'd actually do in your case is just push the bash script stuff down in to Matlab M-code like Cris Luengo suggested, so that your Matlab script is in control of the whole process. The functionality of this bash script could be easily written in Matlab using the `system()` function and/or `!` construct.